# PR2's `robot claim` Source Code?

Tags: pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there source code out there somewhere for the PR2's mechanism for  [claiming a robot](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_robot/Tutorials/Starting%20up%20the%20PR2#Claim_the_robot)? I used to know where it was when I had a PR2.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265262/pr2%27s-%60robot-claim%60-source-code?/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2017-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's in the pr2-core debian package (not a ROS package):

The executable: https://github.com/pr2-debs/pr2-core/blob/master/root/usr/bin/robot

And the library: https://github.com/pr2-debs/pr2-core/tree/master/root/usr/lib/robot

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-06-30**:
Looks my easter eggs are still there, and ClearPath has added a few of their own.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2017-06-30**:
Thanks! `austin love`